# Iexpress set extraction path?

Tags: iexpress

I'm trying to extract a handful of `.jpgs` to a certain directory `(%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads)`

I've tried using a `.bat` file:

```
@echo off
rem install.bat
mkdir %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads
echo %ERRORLEVEL% created directory %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads
copy * %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads
echo %ERRORLEVEL% copied files
del %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads\install.bat
echo %ERRORLEVEL% success?
```

But this just gives me an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7fTW.png)

I also tried an `.inf` file:

```
[version]  
signature="$CHICAGO$"

[DefaultInstall]
CopyFiles=install.files

[DestinationDirs]
install.files=-1,"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads"

[install.files]    
Kingdom Tower.jpg
Night Bridge.jpg
Seoul.jpg
Singapore Dreams.jpg
```

But this just doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out right after I posted this, derp

Install program needs to be: `cmd /c install.bat` not just `install.bat`